# Virtually free, torsion-free, and locally free groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

A well-known theorem of Stallings says that

*any finitely generated virtually free torsion-free group is free.*

> Is this true without **`finitely generated'** condition?

In other words,

> is every locally free virtually free group free?

Comment: The additive group of the rational number is locally free.

Comment: But it is not virtually free.

Comment: Hence this is was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I presume you know that Swan proved that every group of cohomological dimension one is free, without assuming finite generation?

Comment: Dear Henry, many thanks! Obviously, I had not read Swan's paper (https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0021-8693%2869%2990030-1), because it contains a positive answer to my question (Theorem B). Probably, you may better write an answer to make it clear for everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is Theorem B of Swan's famous paper *Groups of cohomological dimension one*, in which he removes the 'finitely generated' hypothesis from Stallings' theorem. Theorem B states:

> Let $G$ be a torsion-free group. If $G$ has a free subgroup of finite index, then $G$ is free.

[Here](https://dx.doi.org/10.1016%2F0021-8693%2869%2990030-1)'s the paper (apparently not behind a paywall).